# JQuery Onchange Event Not Working on production but working on my local instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#time-popup").change(function (event) {
    if (document.getElementById("time-popup") != null) {
        document.getElementById("popup_Billed_").value = document.getElementById("time-popup").value;
    }
});
```

While clik on time-popup textbox feild no event fired.
even no alert for

```
alert($("#time-popup"));
```

please suggest

Comment: Can you provide a link or something.

Comment: Since this involves 2 completely different environments there could be a lot factors outside of being a code issue.  Does production have the same version of js code as your localhost?  Is there other js error happening else where?...  I would look at environments before jumping to it being a code issue.

Comment: Its not going inside onchange because its getting undefined while event occures

Answer (score 1):

Try Event Delegation:

```
$(document).on('change', "#time-popup", function (event) {
...
```

From the [docs](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

Comment: Getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error on console for $(document).on("change","#time-popup",function (event) {

Answer (score 1):

First you can write all in jQuery like below (commented code is not required)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#time-popup").change(function (event) {
        /*if ($("#time-popup").length > 0) { */
            $("#popup_Billed_").val($("#time-popup").val());
       /*}*/
       // above if condition not required because you are 
       //running this code for onchange event of time-popup 
       // only so no need to check if it exist or not.
    });
});
```

Check console error for your html and be sure that there should not be any duplicate Id for `time-popup` or `popup_Billed` is present in view source of the page.

Also if time-popup is getting created dynamically then you should bind change event using `.on()`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("change","#time-popup",function (event) {
         $("#popup_Billed_").val($("#time-popup").val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Getting Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function error on console for $(document).on("change","#time-popup",function (event) {

Comment: are you using $(document).ready(function(){ .... and have put on change inside this ...pls see my answer

Comment: yes jQuery(document).ready(function() { ...... $(document).on("change","#time-popup",function (event) {
     $("#popup_Billed_").val($("#time-popup").val());
});  ..........

Comment: can you share jsfiddle for it and which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#time-popup").on('change',function () {
            document.getElementById("popup_Billed_").value = document.getElementById("time-popup").value;
          });
});
```